# Comparing string from text file to another list in C

Tags: c

I've a lab to compare two strings one from an array that is given in the code and another from a .txt file:

```
while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c" c);
    name1 = c;
    test = strcmp(name, name1);
```

I get the error:

> comparison between pointer and integer

I would like to know how to change the `C` variable so that I can compare it with `strcmp()`?

Edit:

```
int validName(const char name[ ]) 
{
  char name1[100];
  int test, c;

  FILE *fp = NULL;
  fp = fopen("keywords.txt", "r");

  if (fp == NULL){
      printf("error \n");
      exit(1);
 }

  while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    fscanf(fp, "%s", name1);
    test = strcmp(name, name1);
    printf("test =%d\n", test);
    if(test ==0){
        c = 1;
    }
//  printf("test1");

}

if (c = 1) {
    return 1;
}
else
    return 0;

fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: what is the type of name1

Comment: char name1[100];

 int test, c;

name1 is a char and name is a const char given in the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Alternative***:You can use `fscanf(fp,"%s",name);` and compare it with `name1`. Instead of taking character by character and forming the string. 
Note: name1 should be `char[]` having some memory. Here both are `char[]` like

***Your error***:You are comparing int and char* in `strcmp`. You need to have to `char*`. You can proceed in the way mentioned above.

```
char name[30],name1[30];
```

---

### int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );

Compare two strings Compares the C string str1 to the C string str2.

This function starts comparing the first character of each string. If they are equal to each other, it continues with the following pairs until the characters differ or until a terminating null-character is reached. This function performs a binary comparison of the characters

***NOTE:*** In order to stop after seeing a match you can simply have

```
if(strcmp(name,name1)==0)
   break;
```

OR

```
 if(strcmp(name,name1)==0)
   {
    //  call some function to process name 
   }
```

**Answer to the last question**: Okay in that case you have to write a custom function. Simply then you ignore all the whitespaces and then compare only the alphanumeric characters. Functions like `isalpha()` etc will be helpful.

Comment: @ameyCU.: In hurry I forgot to mention..check please

Comment: I added my full code I managed to get strcmp to work but now how can I tell it to stop and return 1 if match is found

Comment: @Jimmy.: Please check now hope it helps

Comment: @ameyCU.: Thanks for the comment. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: @coderredoc  Thanks and glad for such enthusiasm :)

Comment: Thanks you been a great help, last question is that some of the comparison is a bit off for example when checking "for" to " for" it shows as not a match so how can change the code to ignore white spaces when comparing?

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to compare nonstring vs string using `strcmp()`.
Declaration of `strcmp()` is

```
int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
```

Also, you can get line by line like this

```
const size_t name1 = 100;
char* line = malloc(name1);
while (fgets(line, name1, fp) != NULL)
{
// bla bla
}
```

Or, you want to hold word by word with whitespaces you can try the code snippet.

```
while(fscanf(fp, " %s", name1) != EOF)
{
    //bla bla
}
```

So, I think your code should be like

```
int validName(const char name[ ]) {
int test;

FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen("keywords.txt", "r");

if (fp == NULL){
    printf("error \n");
    exit(1);
}

const size_t name1 = 100;
char* line = malloc(name1);
while (fgets(line, name1, fp) != NULL)
{
    test = strcmp(name, name1);
    printf("test =%d\n", test);

    /*
    if Return value(test) < 0 then it indicates name is less than name1.

    if Return value(test) > 0 then it indicates name1 is less than name.

    if Return value(test) = 0 then it indicates name is equal to name1.
    */

    if(test == 0) // if name and name1 same
    {
        return /*something*/
    }

}
fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this part of code:

```
while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    fscanf(fp, "%s", name1);
    test = strcmp(name, name1);
    printf("test =%d\n", test);
    if(test ==0){
        c = 1;
    }
```

When you use `getc` first and then use `fscanf` getc will read the first character of fp then fscanf will ignore that character and read from rest of it for exmaple:

keywords.txt:

```
 Template
```

and the passed value is `Template`
so `Template` is stored in name variable and in the name1 `emplate` is stored.

Instead of using:

```
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
```

you can use :

```
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", name1) != EOF)
```

I think you want to stop this loop when `test==0` so instead of using:

```
  if(test ==0){
        c = 1;
    }
```

use:

```
 while (fscanf(fp, "%s", name1) != EOF) {           
        test = strcmp(name, name1);
        printf("test =%d\n", test);
        if (test == 0) {
            fclose(fp);
            return 1;
        }
        //  printf("test1");

    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
```

NOTE: After returning rest of code will not helpful so I putted `fclose` before return.